# rhandsontable does not display anything

Tags: r-markdown, rhandsontable

I am using the `rhandsontable` library in `R` to create a table in my `rmarkdown` file. Just to test, I tried the example code in the package

```
library(rhandsontable)
DF = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                small = letters[1:10],
                dt = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rhandsontable(DF) %>%
  hot_cols(columnSorting = TRUE)
```

However, this does not print **anything** in the `Viewer` tab of `RStudio`. I don't get any error message also. Inserting `rhandsontable` code into a chunk in the markdown down document also has the same result, I get a blank. I am not sure, what is missing, any help here would be very useful. My system info is as follows:

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "4.1"

$year
[1] "2017"

$month
[1] "06"

$day
[1] "30"

$`svn rev`
[1] "72865"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)"

$nickname
[1] "Single Candle"
```

and the `rhandsontable` version is `0.3.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is resolved when I install the github version of the package

```
devtools::install_github("jrowen/rhandsontable", dependencies = T, upgrade_dependencies = T)
```